# How can I best use my objective function to quickly find *a* feasible solution (Gurobi)?

Tags: linear-programming, solver, gurobi

I have a working ILP Gurobi model (exclusively binary variables).  Reducing runtime and finding a feasible solution is of far more value to me than the optimal solution.  Reducing my SolutionLimit to 1 does help.  I realized that my objective function is summing up hundreds of thousands of variables together.  If I don't truly care about optimality, can I somehow simplify my objective function to reduce the burden on the solver?
Here is my current objective function:

```
m.setObjective(quicksum(h[x,y,c,p,t] + v[x,y,c,p,t]
    for x in range(0,Nx)
    for y in range(0,Ny)
    for c in range(0,C)
    for p in range(0,P)
    for t in range(0,T)), GRB.MINIMIZE)
```

Comment: Try setting parameter MIPFocus=1. SolutionLimit=1 is a bit extreme. It means you don't care about the objective at all. In that case, just set the obj to 0.

Comment: MIPFocus=1 was a life saver.  I removed SolutionLimit=1.  I kept the objective as-is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to nitpick but there is no such thing as a "more optimal" solution - "optimal" is already the superlative. In case you are really only looking for a feasible solution without regard for the objective function, you should follow Erwin's advice and don't set an objective function at all. It's hard to believe, though, that your current objective function is completely meaningless, so a better approach is probably to reduce the objective function to include only a few variables and also to set a higher MIPGap to terminate the solve earlier.

Comment: Thanks, I will change my wording.